# Webservice Proxy from Adobe Flex

Tags: web-services, actionscript-3, apache-flex, blazeds

I am creating one Flex application which needs to show results from a webservice, hosted in our network itself. It's an internal application, but due to the strict secured environment, we need to open firewall to access other hosts or services.

For my application, I had opened the firewall from my server. But since Flex calls the webservice from the client, its impractical to open the firewall from all the clients.

I found we can use the proxy service of BlazeDS. I tried that also but didnt succeed. I did a vast search over the internet also, but failed on getting the detailed working way of the proxy service of BlazeDS. Do anyone know how this proxy works? Even we are calling the destination of the BlazeDS, will at any time Flex calls the WSDL url directly from the client?

Thanks in Advance,
Anoop

Comment: So, do you mean that you want to send requests to your restricted by firewall service through another host:port that is already allowed on all client computers? Did you read this http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?105494-Spring-BlazeDS-HTTP-Proxy-Service article?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Its like the clients have only access to the application server, and the app server have access to the webservice. Client directly is not having access to webservice. I cannot implement the way written in the article since am not using Spring. :( if I take the application from the server machine, I am able to get the results from the webservice. But when I tried to access from another machine, it failed. Gave me fault 'Send Failed'.

Comment: proxy-config.xml does not require spring: http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=lcarch_4.html , http://livedocs.adobe.com/blazeds/1/blazeds_devguide/help.html?content=rpc_httpws_05.html

Comment: I am using proxy-config only. But I am getting the error "Unable to load WSDL. If currently online, please verify the URI and/or format of the WSDL (null)". But it is working when I access the flex application from the server. Do you know whether at any point the blazeds proxy will call the wsdl directly. :(

Comment: You can check with Charles if your app on server connects to wsdl directly or through proxy.